# Wordle program prints wrong letters, I need help debugging the issue

Tags: arrays, list, input, mit-scratch, wordle-game

[Link to project](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/798882651)

Wordle Scratch code has a bug: Whenever an input is given by the user the program prints 5 of the same sprite with the same costume regardless of input. The program should print all letters in user input as 5 separate sprites with costumes matching their letter

I tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OsCe1btRZo) tutorial however I get a different result despite copying the code exactly from what I can tell.

Comment: Your code looks like you just stopped following the video after 45 minutes. You may want to continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a block `When I start as a clone` where you set costume to `blank`. This is executed for EVERY clone you create, even from `Answer check` block.

I don't see why you need that `When I start as a clone` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you don't have a script for when your sprite starts as a clone and the fact that your only sprite doesn't have any costumes, meaning that when you clone your sprite, it's going to be the exact same thing unless you add costumes and add a "when I start as a clone" script.